# Echo Exec ("python filepath $variables") Not Working

Tags: php, macos, python-2.7, mamp

I have a bit of backend code that is executed like so:

```
python filepath $inputvariable
```

This code prints out some data. As you can see in the screenshot below, when I run this code through terminal it works flawlessly, outputting the expected value:

`CHI 110^*^Integrated Chinese Level 1 Part 1^*^https://www.amazon.com/Integrated-Chinese-Simplified-Characters-Textbook/dp/0887276385/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1466983577&sr=8-1&keywords=integrated+chinese^*^47.49`

[image]

But I run into issues when I try to run the same code through php:

```
echo exec ("python /Users/USERNAME/Desktop/Exeter_Bookstore_Project/localserver/cont/Scripts/Python/serverside.py $classToSend");
```

This code returns a null value. At first I assumed that I wasn't passing variables through correctly, but `echo $classToSend;` yielded the correct variable. Then I tried having the php execute a hello world python script, but this also worked proving that the issue wasn't in my python interpreter. Then I thought that maybe the python script wasn't forwarding data quickly enough, but the helloworld.py still worked even with a time delay of 3 seconds.

Does anyone have any idea of what I might have done wrong, or do you need more information. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What is the value of the $classToSend variable?

Comment: What permissions are set on the `.py` file, and maybe try using `/usr/bin/python2.7` instead of plain `python`.

Comment: Ok, I think that we are getting closer to the issue. I put in `/usr/bin/python2.7` and got an error message informing me that `File "/Users/alechowe/Desktop/Exeter_Bookstore_Project/lab/Python/amazonParser.py", line 4, in <module>
    from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
ImportError: No module named bs4`

Comment: But that's weird because i have bs4/beautiful soup installed and the program works perfectly when i run it from IDLE or from the terminal.

Comment: Are two versions of Python installed? Try removing 2.7 off the end and/or in terminal do `which python`.

Comment: Just did that. `which python` returns `/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/python`

Comment: Interesting that it would come back with the path inside the framework. You might as well try using `/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/python` once and see what the `exec` command does.